# Как работать с POST данными на endpoint-е?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

По нажатию на кнопку данные передаются Ajax-ом в endpoint POST запросом.
Данные в виде массива json. Т.е. [{data:1}{type:1},{data:2}{type:2}]

В endpoint-е вот такой код:

```
public function api_save_callback( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
    if ( !isset( $request )) {
        $response = new WP_REST_Response( 'Where is params', 400 );
        return $response;
    }
    echo (var_dump($request));
    $response = new WP_REST_Response( 'Ok', 200 );
    return $response;
}
```

Как в коде обращаться к элементам?

P.S
Вот образец POST данных

```
[{"post-id":"1512709186613861455_196691920","post-url":"some_url","post-author":"testing","post-date":"Wed Sep 24 2064 17:47:09 GMT+1000","pic-url":"some_url","post-text":"Sea"},{"post-id":"1512696819280595861_196691920","post-url":"some_url","post-author":"testing","post-date":"Thu Feb 04 2112 17:52:34 GMT+1000","pic-url":"some_url","post-text":"#sea"}]
```

Comment: А что выводит var_dump($request)?

Comment: Данных очень много, в комментарий все не входит, но вот в body все самое интересное, то что нужно ["body":protected]=>
  string(617) "[{"post-id":"1512709186613861455_196691920","post-url":"some_url","post-author":"123","post-date":"Thu Sep 25 2064 10:59:09 GMT+1000","pic-url":"some_url","post-text":"Sea"
},{"post-id":"1512696819280595861_196691920","post-url":"some_url","post-author"
:"123","post-date":"Fri Feb 05 2112 11:04:34 GMT+1000","pic-url":"some_url","post-text":"#sea"}]"

Comment: Ну так возьмите body и прогоните эту строку через json_decode ()

Comment: поправьте свой ответ пожалуйста полными командами. может кому понадобится в будущем чтобы не разбираться долго.

Comment: Да, смысл SO именно в том, чтобы оставлять понятные ответы для тех, кто ищет подобное для себя. Ответ поправил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Декодирование json в WordPress выполняется так:

```
$array = json_decode( $request, true );
```

Второй параметр true если нужен ассоциативный массив.

В исходном коде класса WP_REST_Request (файл wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-request.php) есть функция get_body(). Судя по её коду, она должна возвращать строку запроса:

```
$body = $request->get_body();
```

Таким образом, полный код для получения данных выглядит так:

```
$body = $request->get_body();
$data_array = json_decode( $body, true );
```

Comment: $params = $request->get_params(); - vardump($params) возврящает array(0) {
}

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = json_decode( $request->get_body(), true );
```

Далее к элементам можно обращаться в цикле:

```
foreach($data as $item){echo $item['some_index']};
```